# normal distribution and weak convergence

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence, weak-lp-spaces

is true that if I have the normal distribution $\mu_n \sim N(0,\frac{1}{n^2})$, then it converges weakly to $\mu \sim N(0,0)$?

Comment: It converges weakly to a point mass at 0, often denoted $\delta_0$, which satisfies $\int f(x) \delta_0(dx) = f(0)$.

Comment: @snar Which, if you think about it, is the same as $N(0,0)$; of course that's very curious notation

Answer (score 2):

If $X_n$ has $N(0,\frac  1{n^{2}})$ distribution then $EX_n^{2}=\frac  1{n^{2}} \to 0$. This implies that $X_n \to 0$ in probability, hence weakly. (You can interpret $N(0,0)$ as the distribution of the zero random variable though this notation is rarely used).

Comment: Some relevant facts with links to proofs (for OP's sake): "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_2"